# Rename all files in a folder to their SHA1 hash

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

I would like to rename all files in a folder to their SHA1 HASH value.

I have a command line utility that I can use `"sha1.exe -s"` to echo out the SHA1 Hash value but I need to rename all the files in that folder to match it (no extension).

Essentially, I would like it to function like this:

```
rename file.exe (sha1.exe -s file.exe)
```

In practice turns out something like this:

```
forfiles /p E:\software\sha1 /c "cmd /c rename @file (sha1.exe -s @file)"
```

I am open to using other resources such as Powershell if that's what is required.

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file `hasher.bat` (for ease place `sha1.exe` in same folder):

```
@ECHO OFF
SET FULLNAME=%~f1
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('sha1.exe -s %FULLNAME%') do SET hash=%%a
ren %FULLNAME% %hash%
```

Now in CMD you can run the batch using following statement:

`for %A IN (C:\PathToFolder\*) DO C:\SomeFolder\hasher.bat "%A"`

Comment: This is perfect!

For simplicity sake I put sha1.exe in the "c:\windows" folder and created another batch file that can invoke the hasher.bat file:

     for %%A IN (C:\PathToFolder\*) DO C:\SomeFolder\hasher.bat "%%A"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with a `forfiles` command, nor a `/P` option to any `for`-like commands I know, so I'm guessing that `E:\software\sha1` is a text file listing the files you want to operate on, one path per line.

```
Get-Content E:\software\sha1 |
    foreach {
        ren $_ (sha1.exe -s $_)
    }
```

or if you're typing it by hand:

```
gc E:\software\sha1 | % { ren $_ (sha1.exe -s $_) }
```

Comment: Actually the `/P` option accepts a directory to get the listing to operate from. So if you replace `Get-Content` with `Get-ChildItem`, you're golden.

Answer (score 0):

The .Net framework has hashing features built in. Here's how to do it in powershell without using additional utilities.

```
function Rename-FilesToSHA {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
    [ValidateScript({ Test-Path $_ })]
    $Path
    )

    $hasher = [System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm]::Create('SHA1')
    $files = Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse | Where-Object {-not $_.PSIsContainer}

    foreach ($file in $files) {

    $fs = New-Object IO.FileStream($file.FullName, 'Open')
    $sb = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder

    $hasher.ComputeHash($fs) | ForEach-Object { [void]$sb.Append($_.ToString("x2")) }
    $fs.Close()

    $file | Rename-Item -NewName $sb.ToString()
    }
}
```

For example to rename all files under c:\temp run the command:

```
Rename-FilesToSHA -Path c:\temp
```